# program falling apart at the "if" statement and forcing a category "B"

Tags: c#

ok so this program keep falling apart at the first "if" statement and keep bringing me to caragory B any tips?where is it failing? what code needs to be added or taken out?

```
using System;

class Program
{
    enum Numbers { standard = 1, express = 2, same = 3 };

    const int A = 1, B = 2;
    const int Y = 3, N = 4;
    static void Main()
     {

        double cost, LB;
        int Number_of_items ;
        int myNumbers;
        char catagory = 'A';
        char surcharge = 'Y';

        Console.WriteLine("please enter the type of shiping you want");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 1:standard shipping.");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 2:express shipping.");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 3:same day shipping.");

        myNumbers = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        switch ((Numbers)myNumbers)
        { 
            case Numbers.standard:
                Console.WriteLine("thankyou for chooseing standerd shipping");
                Console.WriteLine("please choose a catagory");
                Console.Write("Type A or B to make your selection");
                catagory = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                {      if (catagory==A)
                {
                    Console.Write("please enter the number of items");
                    Number_of_items = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    cost = 3 * Number_of_items;

                    Console.Write("is this shipment going to alaska or Hawaii? (Y or N)");
                    if (surcharge==Y)
                    {
                        cost = cost + 2.50;

                        Console.WriteLine("Total cost is {0}." , cost);
                    }
                    else 
                        Console.WriteLine("total cost is {0}." , cost);


                }
                else
                    Console.Write("please enter the weight in pounds");
               LB =  double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                cost = 1.45 * LB;
                Console.WriteLine("is this shipment going to alaska or Hawaii? (Y or N)");
        }
                if (surcharge==Y)
                {
                    cost = cost + 2.50;

                        Console.WriteLine("Total cost is {0}." , cost);
                }
                else 
                        Console.WriteLine("total cost is {0}." , cost);

                break;


                case Numbers.express:
                Console.WriteLine("thankyou for chooseing Express Shipping");
                Console.WriteLine("please choose a catagory");
                Console.Write("Type A or B to make your selection");
                catagory = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    {       if (catagory==A)
                        Console.Write("please enter the number of items");
                        Number_of_items = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        cost = 4 * Number_of_items;
                        {
                    Console.Write("is this shipment going to alaska or Hawaii? (Y or N)");
                    if (surcharge==Y)
                    {
                        cost = cost + 5.00;

                        Console.WriteLine("Total cost is {0}." , cost);
                    }
                    else 
                        Console.WriteLine("total cost is {0}." , cost);


                    }
                        if (surcharge==B)


                            Console.Write("please enter the weight in pounds");
               LB =  double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                cost = 2.50 * LB;
                Console.WriteLine("is this shipment going to alaska or Hawaii? (Y or N)");
                    }
                if (surcharge==Y)
                {
                    cost = cost + 5.00;

                        Console.WriteLine("Total cost is {0}." , cost);
                }
                else 
                        Console.WriteLine("total cost is {0}." , cost);
            break;





                case Numbers.same:
                Console.WriteLine("thankyou for chooseing Same Day Shipping");
                Console.WriteLine("please choose a catagory");
                Console.Write("Type A or B to make your selection");
                catagory = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (catagory == A)
                    Console.Write("please enter the number of items");
                    Number_of_items = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    cost = 5.50 * Number_of_items;

                    Console.Write("is this shipment going to alaska or Hawaii? (Y or N)");
                    if (surcharge==Y)
                    {
                        cost = cost + 8.00;

                        Console.WriteLine("Total cost is {0}." , cost);
                    }
                    else 
                        Console.WriteLine("total cost is {0}." , cost);



                if (surcharge==B)

                    Console.Write("please enter the weight in pounds");
               LB =  double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                cost = 3.00 * LB;
                Console.WriteLine("is this shipment going to alaska or Hawaii? (Y or N)");

                if (surcharge==Y)
                {
                    cost = cost + 8.00;

                        Console.WriteLine("Total cost is {0}." , cost);
                }
                else 
                        Console.WriteLine("total cost is {0}." , cost);

                break;
        }
  Console.ReadLine();

    }//End Main()
}//End class Program
```

Comment: if i input "A" it still brings me to "B"

Comment: That is a very very long method. I'd suggest you break it down into simple small methods and use unit tests to verify that each of the small methods behave as they should.

Comment: i have broken it down but it fails at the same spot in all 3 cases

Comment: Wow, that is a bit hard to read. I think you are missing some block curly braces in there after a few of your ifs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A is an int variable to which you assigned the value 1.
You probably meant to do:
if (catagory=='A')
not
if (catagory==A)

Comment: You may also want to test for upper and lower case (e.g. if ( (catagory == 'A') || (catagory == 'a') ). Also, you are not prompting for user input before: if (surcharge == Y) which should also be testing for 'Y' not Y.